# How change state in GET method with wiremock

Tags: mocking, stubbing, wiremock

I slightly don't understand one moment. How change state in my GET method? I understand, that need to use scenatios, but my code don't work. Always state = status one. (I'm using json)

I have one method GET, whose state i want to change after check him again.
For example (three json file - three state - one GET method):

First scenario

```
{
"scenarioName": "check status event",
"requiredScenarioState": "Started",
"request": {
"method": "GET",
"urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration/[0-9]+"
},

"response": {
"status": 200,
"jsonBody": {
"status": "status one",
},
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
}
}
```

Second scenario

```
"scenarioName": "check status event",
"requiredScenarioState": "Started",
"newScenarioState": "status two",
"request": {
"method": "GET",
"urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration/[0-9]+"
},

"response": {
"status": 200,
"jsonBody": {
"status": "status two",
},
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
}
}
```

Third scenario

```
"scenarioName": "check status event",
"requiredScenarioState": "status two",
"newScenarioState": "status three",
"request": {
"method": "GET",
"urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration/[0-9]+"
},

"response": {
"status": 200,
"jsonBody": {
"status": "status three",
},
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
}
}
```

Or may I using some delay for change state in once method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `newScenarioState` element on the first stub too, otherwise you can never get out of the `Started` state.

`newScenarioState` is the state the scenario will transition to when the stub is matched.